# low latency kernel corrupted

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I installed the lowlatency kernel to deal with a screen tearing issue. That has become corrupted.

I want now to

- re-install the current lowlatency kernal to replace the corrupted version
- install the current generic kernel beside it
- have each as options on the grub menu

How can I do this?

Comment: Ordinary `sudo apt install --reinstall <package_name>` will also reinstall kernels. Do you need help figuring out the package name? Installing two kernels using apt will automatically add both to GRUB for convenient selection at boot.

Comment: @user535733 Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@user535733 : Thanks**

Kernel packages are named `linux-modules-`*kernel_version* so:

To reinstall the current kernel

```
 sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r)
```

Or *for example*  in the usual case where the kernel is the generic version: `linux-modules-<version-number>-generic` :

```
 sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic
```